# Is it safe to use celery with non thread-safe code?

Tags: django, multithreading, celery, django-celery

What is the best way to handle non thread-safe code with Celery?

```
@app.task
def do():
   # non thread-safe code here
```

Comment: use context manager ```with transaction.atomic():``` or put a lock on, for example, redis and unlock when your non-thread-safe part of code is completed

Comment: @MikołajRutecki ,thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care about your task implementation by your self.

IF this task is running as a group for example and handles some currencies, like writing variables, write objects to database, write file content,... then your data could be inconsistent.